# How can change the dress of the masque when click on the dress it should be applied to the masque

Tags: javascript

```
    $("#tail").kendoFlatColorPicker({
        preview: false,
        value: "#000",
        change: select
    });

    $("#head").kendoFlatColorPicker({
        preview: false,
        value: "#e15613",
        change: select
    });
```

i tried this code using color picker .please help me for manque dress changing

i want my website look like as below link please see it and help me
http://glamstorm.com/en/fittingroom/clothes

Comment: why downvote its valid question? u should always explain as comment when u downvote a question stackoverflow should make it mandatory

Comment: thnqq arjun chaudhary for ur support

Comment: its ok person who dont know the answer do like this it happens with me also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude unstead of click use hovering would look awesome and different from other siteDoing that is Very simple. Give an id to your images so they can be uniquely identified. In the mouseover function, either pass the id of the current image and map it to another, or directly pass the id of the image you want to swap.

```
<img src="one.jpg" id="one" onmouseover="swapImage('two')">
<img src="two.jpg" id="two" onmouseover="swapMappedImage(this.id)">
```

so when one image is hovered another image is changed.

> OR for ur clicking

if you want to fire the event  on your image set this attribute, to each one :

```
<image src=".." onclick="changeMainImage('put here the path of you main image');" >
```

then you can put this function on a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeMainImage(url)
    {
          /*now here you have to get the element of you main top image, supposing that you are usins as an id "myMainImage" ok!
           */
          var mainImage = document.getElementById('myMainImage');
          // here we are setting to the maing image the path you receive as a param
           mainImage.src = url;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thnq for your replay sir .but instead of mouse hover i need the image change on click it self.

http://glamstorm.com/en/fittingroom/clothes

please see this link .This is what i wanna do.

Comment: i am not sir i am also a student try above code and let me know

Comment: me still trying becauz im new to this field so trying

Comment: what happened why so much time?

Comment: actually i am totally new to it,i am still a learner trying out with my new ideas so it took time